# How to reload the same viewcontroller with passed data using UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, swipe, viewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Sometimes it's difficult to come up with an accurate title for a question... but here goes:

I have a viewcontroller that I want to re-load with new data using UISwipeGestureRecognizer, I want to basically say "if UISwipeGestureRecognizer direction is up, x = x + 1 (I would also have a x = x - 1 for a down swipe).  There are images that are dependent on passed integer that would automatically load also. Ideally, it would appear as if the swipe animated to a new page, but really it would be the same viewcontroller with different data.

It's difficult to ask this question in a coherent way, but I hope someone can get the gist of what I'm trying to do. If not, apologies. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two Swipe Gesture Recognizers to your main view, one to detect the swipe up, and the other the swipe down, like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Your gesture recognizers:
    var swipeUpGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
    var swipeDownGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()

    // Your x variable:
    var x = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup your gesture recognizers:
        swipeUpGestureRecognizer.direction = .up
        swipeUpGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(swipeUpAction))

        swipeDownGestureRecognizer.direction = .down
        swipeDownGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(swipeDownAction))

        // Inserting the gesture recognizers into the main view:
        self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUpGestureRecognizer)
        self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDownGestureRecognizer)

    }

    // Methods:
    func swipeUpAction() {
        // Update your data here!
        x = x + 1
    }

    func swipeDownAction() {
        // Update your data here!
        x = x - 1
    }

}
```

This should work just fine! Good luck!

Comment: @tfcamp I made a mistake on my previous code, at "Inserting the gesture recognizers into the main view" I previously used "addSubview" but it should be "addGestureRecognizer" (I already edited it), check it up again! I tested it on Xcode and it just works.

Comment: Thanks!!! Ran the change and everything is working well. Very helpful, thank you.